# Best way to extract all solution symbols with Roslyn

Tags: .net, code-generation, roslyn

We've developed in the past a code generation tool based on top of codedom to automate some code generation for our solution. The solution was parsing the full code tree to store custom information needed for our tool but I always found it quite a duplicate of what VS was already doing in the background. With the introduction of Roslyn I was expecting to have a better way to extract symbols definitions from the compiler, allowing me to query directly a solution symbols' table without requiring me to store custom data for our needs. We don't need to change the code in anyway, we just need to read the objects definitions like Classes, Specific methods, metadata and so on.

My question is, what is required to read those symbols? Do I need to parse again all projects/documents looking for those or is there an API which allows me to extract those symbols?

Comment: Are you writing a VS extension or a standalone tool? You're looking for Roslyn's `SemanticModel`.

Comment: I'm writing a VS extension yes, From my little understanding it still requires to go through the all syntax tree and fetch all the semantic models. My hope was if Roslyn (or VisualStudio Workspace) already had some API to easily access this information.

Comment: Do you need **all** symbols? Or do you need to find certain types of symbols? (In a comment you mentioned you're looking for derived types as an example). Do you also need to analyze parameter symbols and locals?

Comment: I'll be needing the most of them (1000+ definitions) our generator automates some frontend development, we generate exposed services, value object definitions, etc. When we save a file, we inspect which kind of object we saved and generate the corresponding client side code using T4 templates.

Comment: So not sure if it's already answered, but yes, the VS workspace already can give you symbol linformation. As @SLaks has observed, this is just a matter of you grabbing compilations and walking symbols that way, or being an analyzer if that's appropriate for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a symbol based action (with `AnalysisContext.RegisterSymbolAction`), which gets called whenever a symbol is analyzed. But because you don't just want individual symbols, you'd probably be better off with registering a compilation start action, which internally would register a symbol action. This way, in the compilation end action you'd have all symbol info belonging to the whole project.

Comment: So, I got it, it would depend on the compilation process of the project and wouldn't be available when the project was loaded unless I would build manually a Compilation Unit from the source, right?

Comment: You don't have to build manually. Inside VS, diagnostic analyzers are executed automatically. So when the project is loaded, the analyzer is triggered. Check out for example [this](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2015/04/30/learn-roslyn-now-part-10-introduction-to-analyzers/) intro tutorial for more info.

Comment: I need to try this. So I'll assume the analyser handler will be recalled once we change a symbol definition

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`SymbolFinder` class](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/FindSymbols/SymbolFinder_References.cs), which you can use to find all references to a symbol within the SemanticModel for each project in the (MEF-imported) VisualStudioWorkspace.

Comment: Thanks but I think I didn't express myself clear (english is not my main language). What I'm looking for is to fetch all specific symbols (eg: All Classes extending BaseClass or with a specific metadata) and not references from a specific Symbol.

Comment: @JoãoFernandes: Classes extending a base class is just a specific kind of reference.